# Delphi - writing application for IOS, MacOsx and windows?

Tags: ios, windows, macos, delphi

I would like to make sure I understand the powerful of Delphi correctly. it is possible to write code which will run on those three platforms: windows, MacOSx and IOS?!

1. How comes?
2. Is it possible to upload the delphi iOS app to Appstore?
3. Is it possible the program will run on linux as well?
4. Which Delphi version should I study ?

Answer (score 4):

Q: Will a Delphi program run under Windows, MacOS and IOS?

A: Yes.

But Mac OSX support is only for newer versions of Delphi XE, and IOS support is for Delphi XE3 and is still in beta: http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/ios-development.

Delphi use to support Linux under the (failed) [Kylix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kylix_%28software%29) brand.

The [FreePascal](http://www.freepascal.org/) and [Lazarus](http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/) projects are alive, well and fully open-source.

Free Pascal supports Linux ... Windows (Win32 and Win64; Win95, Win/XP, Win7, etc.), DOS,  WinCE, OS/2, MorphOS, Nintendo GBA, Nintendo DS, and Nintendo Wii ... FreeBSD, Haiku, Mac OS X/iOS/Darwin.  And even Raspberry Pi: http://wiki.freepascal.org/Lazarus_on_Raspberry_Pi

Additionally, Delphi XE on .Net should run on both Windows and Linux implementations (.Net and Mono, respectively).

'Hope that helps

Comment: Delphi for .NET is dead, and has been for a few versions. It was replaced by `Delphi Prism`, which has now also been discontinued (although the product licensed by EMBT as Delphi Prism, [Oxygene](http://www.remobjects.com/oxygene), existed before Prism and is still continuing to be developed). iOS support existed in XE2, but was removed for XE3 and is coming back with XE4; it's not in XE3 at all. OSX support was added in XE2 and remains in XE3, and is being enhanced in the upcoming XE4. Android development is due in XE5, due out this fall according to rumor.

Comment: @KenWhite which one should I study, feel free to format your comment into an answer.

Comment: @0x90 - it depends on what you want to do.  To get up to speed with Embarcadero Delphi for IOS today, download the beta.  To specialize in IOS apps for the app store ... I'd really encourage you to buy a Mac workstation and learn Objective C (IMHO).  To program IOS apps in Delphi/Pascal - you can either wait for the non-beta Delphi IOS compiler, or use Free Pascal: [Can you use FreePascal App on the Mac OS X App Store?](http://lists.lazarus.freepascal.org/pipermail/lazarus/2011-January/060041.html), [App Store acceptance :-)](http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=12606.0).

Comment: @0x90: I can't answer that, because there is no "right answer". XE4 and XE5 aren't out yet, so I can't tell you what they will be able to do or judge how well they do it. FireMonkey is supposed to be the new cross-platform GUI library, but since it's not out for all platforms (and I don't do OSX development) I can't judge how well it will work out for that purpose.

Comment: @0x90: Ken is correct: there is no "one right answer".  My two cents: 1) If you want Delphi/Pascal syntax and functionality, at least take a look at both the IOS beta *and* Lazarus/FreePascal.  2) If you want to specialize in IOS, consider investing in a Mac Workstation and learning Objective C.  3) If you want cross-platform (IOS, Android, Blackberry and Windows 8), consider an HTML5/Javascript framework like [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/).  IMHO...

Comment: Your details are a little off. OSX support was XE2. iOS support was XE2 but removed in XE3. About to be re-instated with a new native ARM compiler in XE4 to be released in a matter of days. And your .net details were off too. You should correct these details.

Comment: Oh and there is SmartMobile Studio which underneath uses DWScript as a very much Delphi-like scripting language. The resulting HTML5 applications run on virtually any web-browser/device combination, including iOS, Android, PC and Mac. http://smartmobilestudio.com/about/

Answer (score 1):

There is the [Delphi FireMonkey](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/firemonkey) framework, developed to provide single-source cross-platform development. It was included with Delphi starting in XE2.

Delphi XE2 FireMonkey natively supports 32-bit and 64-bit Windows, and 32-bit Mac OS X and iOS.

Delphi XE3 dropped the iOS support.

In December 2012, the Embarcadero R&D team [was reported to have been working on](http://delphibistro.com/?p=206) iOS and Android support, with Windows 8 ARM and Linux server also coming.

It is possible in XE3 to upload an OS X app to the App Store. Embarcadero created [a video of how to do it](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W6Zd71_L8aw). It is likely that support for the App Store will be included when iOS support is added back.